# Can Ubuntu Kylin's login screen be substituted/installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, login, kylin

I am currently running an HP Omni100 PC with a Dual-Boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Though somewhat irrelevant, I had to throw that out there. I am a semi-experienced Ubuntu user, and I heavily customize my desktops appearance. I have seen a literal cluster of help for reverting the login screen from Ubuntu Kylin's default login back to Ubuntu's default login screen. I wish to do the opposite. If it is possible, please help with instructions to INSTALL Kylin's login screen. Please don't leave negative feedback, as a beginner, I was forced to ask some basic questions, but I have done some searching on this already and have come up empty handed, and I also do not wish to be blocked from asking future questions. Any system information that can help with this I will try to obtain, and I will post any feedback from terminal for others. currently using moka icons, and arc dark theme with whiteglass mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install kylin-greeter: `sudo apt install kylin-greeter`
2. Configure lighdm: Open the file with `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
3. Find [SeatDefaults] and if not there add that line
4. Below [SeatDefaults] add a line like *greeter-session=kylin-greeter*
5. Save with Ctrl + O. Exit with Ctrl + X.
6. Reboot

Comment: i noticed [SeatDefaults] were not in gray, is that exactly what i type in terminal?

Comment: If already there just add the line below as mentioned in step #4.

Comment: You can use other text editors (eg. gedit) if you feel more confortable with other tools. Just make sure you run any other (graphical) editor with "sudo -H" instead of regular sudo.

Comment: for beginners, i would note that the second command enters into file edit mode so no one gets confused.